# Sdbus-c++ and Bluez-Mesh : Properties Getter in org.bluez.mesh.Element1 interface

Tags: c++, mesh, dbus, bluez

I try to implement the bluez interface (org.bluez.mesh.Element1) on c++ with the lib [`sdbus-cpp`](https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp) but an error occured for the two properties Models and VendorModels.

I have also tried to use [`dbus-cxx`](https://github.com/dbus-cxx/dbus-cxx) but I was unable to implement any complex interfaces.

First, when I try to compile the properties but I got an error on the detection of the properties signatures.

The properties signatures :

- Models : `a(qa{sv})`
- VendorModels `a(qqa{sv})`

The  code :

```
class ElementAdaptator {

public:
    static constexpr const char* INTERFACE_NAME = "org.bluez.mesh.Element1";
    struct VendorModel { uint16_t a; uint16_t b; std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant> c; };
    struct Model { uint16_t a; std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant> c; };


protected:
    ElementAdaptator (sdbus::IObject& object)
        : object_ (object) {

        object_.registerMethod ("MessageReceived").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withInputParamNames ("source", "key_index", "destination", "data").implementedAs ([this](uint16_t source, uint16_t key_index, sdbus::Variant destination, std::vector<uint8_t> data) {  this->MessageReceived (source, key_index, destination, data); });
        object_.registerMethod ("DevKeyMessageReceived").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withInputParamNames ("source", "remote", "net_index", "data").implementedAs ([this](uint16_t source, bool remote, uint16_t net_index, std::vector<uint8_t> data) { this->DevKeyMessageReceived (source, remote, net_index, data); });
        object_.registerMethod ("UpdateModelConfiguration").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withInputParamNames ("model_id", "config").implementedAs ([this](uint16_t model_id, std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant> config) { this->UpdateModelConfiguration (model_id, config); });

        object_.registerProperty ("Index").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ([this]() {  return uint8_t(0); });
        
        
        object_.registerProperty ("Models").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ([this]() { 
            return std::vector<std::tuple<uint16_t, std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant>>>();
        });
        
        object_.registerProperty ("VendorModels").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ([this]() {
            return std::vector<std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant>>> ();
        });

    }

    ~ElementAdaptator () = default;

private:
    virtual void MessageReceived (uint16_t source, uint16_t key_index, sdbus::Variant destination, std::vector<uint8_t> d) = 0;
    virtual void DevKeyMessageReceived (uint16_t source, bool remote, uint16_t net_index, std::vector<uint8_t> data) = 0;
    virtual void UpdateModelConfiguration (uint16_t model_id, std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant> config) = 0;


private:
    sdbus::IObject& object_;
};
```

The errors :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sdbus::Error'
  what():  [org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs] Failed to register object vtable (Invalid argument)
```

After few tests, I was able to determine that the problem came from the detection of the property signature.
I also try to replace the `std::tuple` by a struct but the same error occurred.

```
struct VendorModel { uint16_t a; uint16_t b; std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant> c; };
struct Model { uint16_t a; std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant> c; };
```

```
object_.registerProperty ("Models").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ("a(qa{sv})", [this]() { 
    return std::vector<struct Model >();
});

object_.registerProperty ("VendorModels").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ("a(qqa{sv})", [this]() {
    return std::vector< struct VendorModel > ();
});
```

So I made a clone of the "withGetter" method to specify the property signature manually. This worked for the compilation, when bluez-mesh tries to access the property, it doesn't succeed and crashes.
So I don't know if it's a data type problem or a lib problem.

The modified function :

```
template <typename _Function>
inline PropertyRegistrator& PropertyRegistrator::withGetter(std::string sign, _Function&& callback)
{
    static_assert(function_traits<_Function>::arity == 0, "Property getter function must not take any arguments");
    static_assert(!std::is_void<function_result_t<_Function>>::value, "Property getter function must return property value");

    if (propertySignature_.empty())
        propertySignature_ = sign;

    getter_ = [callback = std::forward<_Function>(callback)](PropertyGetReply& reply)
    {
        // Get the propety value and serialize it into the pre-constructed reply message
        reply << callback();
    };

    return *this;
}
```

And how I call it :

```
object_.registerProperty ("Models").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ("a(qa{sv})", [this]() { 
    return std::vector<std::tuple<uint16_t, std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant>>>();
});

object_.registerProperty ("VendorModels").onInterface (INTERFACE_NAME).withGetter ("a(qqa{sv})", [this]() {

    return std::vector<std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, std::map<std::string, sdbus::Variant>>> ();
});
```

Can you try to help me please ?

Comment: After more test, this seems to be a problem when propertie's type is a `std::vector` of a `struct`, a `std::tuple` or a `std::pair`

Comment: A solution that I have found is to use a `sdbus::Struct<T, T, ...>` instead of a classic c++ `struct`  object in my `std::vector`